# What is the difference between ajax success function parameter data and response?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Both response and data bringing me the proper response but what is the difference between them.

```
 $("button").click(function(){
$.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){ //if I put response instead of data is also working
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
 });
```

But, I want to know when should I go for response and data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the argument name. You can call it whatever you want. You could call it `foo` and it would work the same way.

> All arguments passed to the function are treated as the names of the identifiers of the parameters in the function to be created, in the order in which they are passed.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

You can also use the `arguments` object to access the arguments: `arguments[0]` would work the same too.

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference at all as value returned by your service is placed on the function first argument.

You could even do instead of `function(data, status)` the following :

```
function(this_is_my_data, status)
```

as it is on the first argument of your function, it will be filled with your endpoint response.